# Python Regular Expression expression excluiding string containing pattern match

Tags: python, regex

I want to create a regular expression to match url links that contain underscore character but I don´t what to match a specific string containing undercore. Bellow are some example with and without matchs indicated:
    
    "site.com/_price_" -> Match
    
    "site.com/price" -> No Match
    
    "site.com/_Desde_" -> No Match - This is important

I have tried the following patterns without success

```
"\[_](?!\_Desde_)"
"\(?!\_Desde_)\[_]"
"\[\_](^\_Desde\_)"
```

Comment: Like [`_(?!Desde_)[^_]*_`](https://regex101.com/r/uZYt8U/1)?

Comment: Perfect @WiktorStribiżew works for me, many thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Please post your answer when you are sure it's the correct one.

Comment: @Rahul: Sure, OP did not provide the exact output, but perhaps, that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
_(?!Desde_)[^_]*_
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZYt8U/1)

It matches

- `_` - an underscore
- `(?!Desde_)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the `_` is followed with `Desde_` substring
- `[^_]*` - 0+ chars other than `_`
- `_` - an underscore.